# Mixed Effects Model Using Censored Data

Tags: mixed-model, nonparametric, censoring, frailty

I am attempting to analyze left-censored hormone data collected in a repeated measures design, and am having some difficulty employing an appropriate method to account for the censored nature of the data. Hormone values were collected at two different time points across three populations, with each population receiving a treatment drug or a vehicle control. Ideally, I would to assess treatment and population as main effects and collection time point as a random effect in a linear mixed-effects model.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Frailty models are the survival model analogue to mixed models.

Comment: @HuyPham Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into this immediately.